# embedding lua code in c

Tags: c, lua

I am attempting to follow the besic guide given [here](http://heavycoder.com/tutorials/lua_embed.php) on embedding lua into C.  I copied the code verbatim into my own embed.c file and executed the exact compiler command listed:

```
cc -o embed embed.c \
            -I/usr/local/include \
            -L/usr/local/lib \
            -llua -llualib
```

I get the error:

```
embed.c:19:14: error: invalid storage class for function ‘openlualibs’
```

After which I moved the functions outside of `main`, compiled again, and got:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llualib
```

I am at a loss for why I cannot compile this.  lua is installed properly.  has anyone else encountered these problems?  If this is a bad tutorial, please feel free to simply direct me to a batter one.

Comment: The linker claims it has searched the paths you gave it and was unable to find the library in question.  Is there, in fact, a file called `liblualib.so` or `liblualib.a` in `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: @BrianCain no.  there is in fact no `liblualib.a` or `liblualib.so` anywhere in `/usr`.  any idea what I need to install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On some Linux distributions you may need to install the `lua-devel` (or similar named) package, in order to get the proper header files and library symlinks required for compiling and linking projects against the package.  If you do have a `liblualib-<version>.so.<version>`, for example `liblualib-5.so.5.0`, you may need to install the devel package.

Starting with lua 5.1, `liblualib` does not exist.  Here is the release announcement: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2005-05/msg00186.html

Comment: I am using ArchLinux.  I've searched for `lua-devel` in `pacman` and gotten no results

Comment: Debian-based distros usually call it `X-dev` (as opposed to `X-devel` in redhat-alikes).  Not sure where Arch falls, but it seems worth a look under `lua-dev`.

Comment: Searching the package database for ArchLinux, it appears `liblualib` does _not_ exist for Arch.  Only liblua.so (in package `lua`) exists.  I'll keep this answer around for posterity, in case someone else has a similar problem that may be solved by it.

Comment: And I don't see a reason for the downvote, +1 for compensating.

Answer (score 1):

I've had somewhat similar problems when embedding Lua. What I found that works for me is linking the dynamic link library (dl) and the math library (m). The math library may not be necessary if you're not using the lmath standard library.

```
cc -o embed embed.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -llua -lm -ldl
```

This, of course, assumes that /usr/local/ is where the Lua files are installed, which is probably true.

As for the tutorial you linked to, I think it may be very out of date. Besides liblualib no longer existing, there are individual functions to open each standard library. These are the luaopen_* functions. [Here's the relevant 5.1 reference manual entry.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5) (I assume you're using 5.1, since that seems to be the version available in the packages) As for a better tutorial, I suggest the [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.html) book. Unfortunately, it was written for Lua 5.0. It is still mostly relevant, but I suggest you look over the relevant sections of the 5.1 reference manual, too.